# Copying array form class

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, wordpress

I have a select menu that makes the content of a table change for each option 
(first, second)

what am trying to do is copying the content of the table [that I just can access its element by class name "bullet-item" ] then add some text to it when the user chooses an option 
then display the new content.

I use the following code but it doesn't work.
nothing changes in my tables
I think the problem is in the array coping

what am trying to do is like this video 
https://www.useloom.com/share/772743b97bbc4ac5839e418bfb527d78

*Note I can't use different id or classes because I use WordPress table

this is the select menu

```
      <select id="select" >
      <option value="first">First</option>
       <option value="secoend">Secoend</option>
        </select>
```

this is the table

```
 <div class="bullet-item" title=""><span class="text">Point of sale with one 
 single login account</span></div>
 <div class="bullet-item" title=""><span class="text">Manage inventory of 50 
  products</span></div>
 <div class="bullet-item" title=""><span class="text">Manage sales 
  invoices</span></div>
 <div class="bullet-item" title=""><span class="text">Manage Purchase 
  Invoices</span></div>
<div class="bullet-item" title=""><span class="text">Detailed reports</span> 
</div>
<div class="bullet-item" title=""><span class="text">Technical support 
throughout the subscription period</span></div>
  <div class="bullet-item" title=""><span class="text">Calculate the VAT 
value</span></div>
 <div class="bullet-item" title=""><span class="text">Training for your 
  team</span></div>
  <a href="/en/pos/?add-to-cart=203" target="_self" class="button primary"  
  style="border-radius:10px;">
   <span>add to cart</span>
    </a>
    </div>
```

and this is the jquery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
         // Your code in here  
         $(document).ready(function(){
          var theOrginal =[];
           var forOption1=[];
           var forOption2=[];
          $('.bullet-item').each(function(index, obj) {
          theOrginal.push($(this).text());
           });
          console.log(theOrginal);
          $("#select").change(function(){

         var selected = $("#select").children("option:selected").val();
         if(selected.localeCompare("first")==0){
         forOption1=[];
    for(var i=0;i<theOrginal.length;i++){
     forOption1.push(arr[i]+"2");}
     console.log(forOption1);
      $('.bullet-item').each(function(index, obj) {
      $(this).text() =forOption1[index];
      });
      }
     else{
      forOption2=[];
      for(var i=0;i<theOrginal.length;i++){
      forOption2.push(arr[i]+"3");}
      console.log(forOption2);
      $('.bullet-item').each(function(index, obj) {
      $(this).html( forOption2[index]);
         });
       }
         });
       }); 
       });
```

Comment: What exactly is/isn't working?

Comment: Off topic: Your inner `document.ready` function is redundant.

Comment: @nurdyguy I  don't know just nothing appears

Comment: Are you looking at the browser's developer console?  In most cases "nothing happens" is accompanied by an error message in the console which should point you in the right direction.  If that doesn't get you there, please include enough of the relevant HTML in the question for people to be able to replicate the problem.

Comment: Why can't you use Ajax and PHP? you can just get data from form push it as input to ajax, do some business logic and append that data to HTML